# "eth_requestAcccounts" does not exist / is not available

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have this piece of code just to connect to MM, but it's saying eth_requestAcccounts does not axist/isnt available. Any tips?

```
    function App() {
  const innitConnection = async () => {
    if(typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined"){
      console.log("You have Metamask!");
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAcccounts",
      });
      console.log(accounts[0]);
    } else {
        console.log("Please install Metamask");
      }
    };
  return (
    <div><button onClick={innitConnection}>Connect</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It is throwing these errors:

inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: The method "eth_requestAcccounts" does not exist / is not available.
{code: -32601, message: 'The method "eth_requestAcccounts" does not exist / is not available.', data: {…}}
code: -32601
data: {origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}
message: "The method "eth_requestAcccounts" does not exist / is not available."
[[Prototype]]: Object

App.js:15 Uncaught (in promise)
{code: -32601, message: 'The method "eth_requestAcccounts" does not exist / is not available.', data: {…}, stack: '{\n  "code": -32601,\n  "message": "The method \"eth…ihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:1:1707)'}
code: -32601
data: {origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}
message: "The method "eth_requestAcccounts" does not exist / is not available."
stack: "{\n  "code": -32601,\n  "message": "The method \"eth_requestAcccounts\" does not exist / is not available.",\n  "data": {\n    "origin": "http://localhost:3000"\n  },\n  "stack": "Error: The method \"eth_requestAcccounts\" does not exist / is not available.

Answer (score 1):

double check what you wrote there. Its: eth_requestAccounts
you wrote "Acccounts" instead of "Accounts".

Answer (score 1):

change Acccounts to Accounts
you are writing wrong spellings.